# Ubuntu 13.04 Wifi is connected but doesn't work after a while

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi

I run ubuntu server 13.04 with kernel 3.8.0. My wireless card is "Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205". The loaded module for this card is `iwlwifi`.

In the past I simply used the `/etc/network/interfaces` and `wpa_supplicant` combo. Then the problems began. I'm connected to my access point but after a short while network communication doesn't work, I even can't ping anything. Then I switched to network manager but it didn't helped anything.

This problem only appears at my home network. I have a d-link wireless router.

And I didn't had the problems when I started to use ubuntu. They appeared at some point but I can't remember whether their was any special event before it began.

Any hints?

Comment: Check this Solution


  [How to enable wifi in ubuntu 12.04 edition][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/432053/how-to-enable-wifi-in-dell-5520-on-ubuntu-12-04-32-64-bit

Answer (score 0):

check **ifconfig** output when you dont have connection. Then if you see wlan0 interface and ip address on it try to ping your **gateway**. If you cant - see the otput of **arp -n**. If there is no record for your gateway ip address then try to reestablish wireless connection. Repeat all this if you dont have connection. If it is the same try with another router or change the configuration of your router - wireless mode b/g/n , channel number etc.. if the problem persists try changing your router.

Comment: ifconfig is in both cases normal. I can't ping my gateway after the connection is "lost". The output of `arp -n` is in both cases equal: http://pastebin.com/2CQcdFyJ

Comment: mode is n/g/b and I changed the channel some time ago without access

Comment: I changed to mode in the router to b/g and since that I had no problems. The question is: why? ;)

Comment: update: it didn't solved the problem. My router menu disabled WPA2 on changing the mode. After I re-enabled the encryption, the problems came back.

Comment: So, without encryption the problem is gone ?

Answer (score 0):

We've suddenly started experiencing this problem with our corporate a/b/g/n network. Based on my research it appears that the firmware for Intel wireless chips does not properly implement the n spec. Why this has just recently become a problem is a question, but we did just get a new wireless controller; perhaps it implements the n spec somewhat differently than the old one did.

Most of the fixes I've seen revolve around disabling the ability to connect to n and instead use a/b/g (hopefully not b). For example, see http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1985079.

The firmware apparently is supplied by Intel and seems to be a long-standing problem (at least since maverick).

Answer (score -1):

Solution/fix and it's a permanent.

Type in command line:

```
sudo modprobe ath5k nohwcrypt
sudo sh -c "echo 'options ath5k nohwcrypt' >/etc/modprobe.d/custom-wireless.conf"
```